# How to make an existing Symfony project --full?

Tags: php, symfony, web, frameworks, command-line-interface

I've made a Symfony app without the option --full inside the command line.

Further in the time, I realize that I need it.

```
symfony new codeOfTest
```

How to include required packages to add --full in an existing Symfony project ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any option that would let you do that.  Far easier to just create a new project with the --full option and then copy whatever code you have already written over.  It's also possible to simply require the extra bundles using composer i.e. 'composer require orm-pack' to get all the Doctrine stuff.  But you would to know the half a dozen or so bundles.  Easier to just start over.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that automatically.

You could create a new bogus project with the --full option and just copy the dependancies from it's composer.json to your composer.json, then run composer install, that should be all you need !

Comment: Well no.  Just no.  Try it some time and you will realize the errors of your way.  There is more to installing Symfony bundles then just the dependencies.

Comment: @Cerad With the power of symfony flex, symfony extensions can auto-configure themselves on installation. If we're talking about taking a "not --full" project to a "-full" project, this really should do the trick imo.

Comment: For older symfony apps or non-symfony bundles i agree with you ofc